# Using polynom_fit_SMOTE and documentation

Tags: python

I'm trying to use polynom_fit_SMOTE in my work, but I am having trouble importing it. Is it not part of the imblearn package like SMOTE is? Or is there some other package I have to import? I'm finding limited documentation information on polynon_fit_SMOTE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to import polynom_fit_SMOTE is with the smote_variants package. Try putting this at the beginning of your file:

```
import smote_variants as sv
```

Then, later you should be able to use this:

```
oversample = sv.polynom_fit_SMOTE()
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Brandon! That did it, and the way it is written now, the proportion it makes is 1.0. If you wanted a different proportion, do (with 0.5 as an example)

```
oversample = sv.polynom_fit_SMOTE(proportion = 0.5)
```